# Doctor Who: An Outrageous Amount of Running 

Tags: doctor-who

As Donna notes in **The Doctor's Daughter**:

> He saves planets, rescues civilizations, defeats terrible creatures, and *runs a lot. Seriously, there's an outrageous amount of running involved* ..."

I've been an huge **Doctor Who** fan since the relaunch in 2005 and I've often heard it mentioned that there's a lot of running in newer episodes ([video 1](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qsUN9J659xM&t=6s), [video 2](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BZzDvY7qXAg&t=10s), many more).  However, I've seen only a couple of the older episodes (a couple of Tom Baker episodes a long time ago and the Paul McGann movie in the 90s).

I'm just curious: can someone who was a avid watcher of the older episodes (pre-2005) tell me, has a lot of running always been a recognized characteristic of Doctor Who episodes or has it become more prevalent in episodes since the 2005 relaunch, perhaps because of the recent writers or the recent actors that have been playing the Doctor?